# Buzzy Sound-MSI B450 Mortar Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, realtek, soundcard

Suddenly my sound starts to be buzzy (I've checked my speakers they're OK.), my sound card is a **Realtek ALC892**. I've also tried the front panel and it's the same. I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** and since now everυthing was working fine. Any Ideas? When I restart my PC it fixed but after a few minutes again the same problem.

The only easy solution I found is to unload and load ALSA sound driver with this command :

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Is a problem that will be fixed with an update? or it depends on the motherboard's OEM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches,_skips_or_crackling) from ArchWiki. It worked for me on a MSI B450M Bazooka with Fedora 29 when I was listening to music while working and suddenly sound got garbled. This distro uses Pulse Audio, so I just needed to kill and restart the sound server.

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

The problem may come from the newer implementation of Pulseaudio server, which "uses timer-based audio scheduling instead of the traditional, interrupt-driven approach". There's an option to change this behavior permanently editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file, and changing the line

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

to

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu, and kudos for including the relevant information from the link in your answer - I have reformatted your answer slightly...